# Search a word in a sentence and represent it as new feature

Tags: r

I am trying to identify the sentence having a particular word(eg. high) from a list of sentences in a dataframe in R, and if that word is present in the sentence of a dataframe, i want to add another column in that dataframe representing 1 for present and 0 for not present.

```
Reviews:                       contains_awesome
Today is an awesome day.       1
The book is good.              0
Awesome weather                1
```

I tried for a particular review as:

```
grep("awesome", tolower(df$Reviews[1]))  # returned output as 1
```

I want to apply this on each sentence in my dataframe to have corresponding value of 0 and 1 in "contains_awesome" column. Please guide, if i should run a for-loop here, but that might be expensive with huge dataset, how should i go for it? I am not very used to R syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` is vectorized, so it can be applied directly on the whole column

```
df$contains_awesome <- as.integer(grepl("awesome", df$Reviews, ignore.case = TRUE))
df$contains_awesome
#[1] 1 0 1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Reviews = c("Today is an awesome day.", "The book is good.", 
"Awesome weather")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Hey thanks akrun, doing something like: df$contains_awesome <- 0
df$contains_awesome[grep("awesome", df$Reviews, ignore.case = T)] = 1, solved the purpose.

Comment: @Sri2110 Just one assignment and no extraction as in the answer is 2x faster.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` returns index of matches

```
grep('awesome', df$Reviews, ignore.case = TRUE)
#[1] 1 3
```

Using `grepl` here is straight-forward since it returns output of length same as the input so that it is easy to add as a new column. But if you want to use `grep` here are couple of approaches.

```
df$contains_awesome <- +(with(df, seq_along(Reviews) %in% 
                                  grep('awesome', Reviews, ignore.case = TRUE)))

df
#                   Reviews contains_awesome
#1 Today is an awesome day.                1
#2        The book is good.                0
#3          Awesome weather                1
```

Or with `match`

```
df$contains_awesome <- +(!is.na(match(1:nrow(df), 
                         grep('awesome', df$Reviews, ignore.case = TRUE))))
```

The `+` in the beginning converts logical values `TRUE`/`FALSE` to 1/0 respectively.